# Service Fabric SetupEntryPoint

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a Guest Executable that needs to access a shared drive (Azure Files). My guest executable is setup in  of the ServiceManifest.xml. I've tried adding a  to launch a "mysetup.bat" file that has the NET USE command that setups up the connection with my Azure Files share. However, I'm getting the following vague errors:

> Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting',
>   Property='CodePackageActivation:Code:SetupEntryPoint'. There was an
>   error during CodePackage activation.The service host terminated with
>   exit code:1

Anybody tried this before? Or at least any tips on how to get more information than the super helpful "Exit code:1"?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, my helpful exit code is 3. Did you found the solution?

Answer (score 3):

SetupEntryPoint is the right place to launch startup tasks. However, depending on what your startup tasks are you may need to specify a RunAsPolicy within the ApplicationManifest.xml.

Here is what I did:

Created a BAT file called 'setup.bat' and added it to my guest executable code folder. Inside this setup.bat file I am doing a NET USE statement to map a network drive to Azure Files share folder.

I added this:

```
<SetupEntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>setup.bat</Program>
    <Arguments></Arguments>
  </ExeHost>
</SetupEntryPoint>
```

to the ServiceManifest node.

```
<Policies>
     <RunAsPolicy CodePackageRef="Code" UserRef="SetupAdminUser" EntryPointType="All" />
</Policies>
```

into the ServiceManifestImport node...

Then added the following

```
  <Principals>
    <Users>
      <User Name="SetupAdminUser">
        <MemberOf>
          <SystemGroup Name="Administrators" />
        </MemberOf>
      </User>
    </Users>
  </Principals>
```

into the ApplicationManifest after the DefaultServices node. It's important that the Principals node comes after the DefaultServices node. Not sure why but it will make it impossible to deploy the application to your cluster.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and what documentation says and I'm still getting the error. I also tried with an empty setup.bat file and it keep saying:


ServiceHostProcess: MySetup.bat started at ‎2017‎-‎02‎-‎13T19:56:50.841058400Z with Process Id 4656 for ApplicationId bc9bf792-57c6-42d6-95b8-3350de901357 terminated unexpectedly with exit code 1 on node id eec59d298de9d615a03ae3ffd119e699


Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting', Property='CodePackageActivation:Code:SetupEntryPoint'.
There was an error during CodePackage activation.The service host terminated with exit code:1


Any idea?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. I tried it but I got the same result when I deploy to Azure, not locally. There is one difference though, I think in your code you are deploying a guest exe and I am deploying a Web API. Can you take a look to my code. It is brand new project with your config xml. literally: open VS, new project, add your XML... thanks in advance https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmWSNr4-2JqMiakLiIMoSZeLUzttJA

Comment: Did you find a solution @ErickB, i am experiencing the same thing

Comment: @poul-k-sørensen No, I did not. If you find it please post it here. Thanks

Comment: @poul-k-sørensen check the new answer I have just posted. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I solved the error: "CodePackageActivation:Code:SetupEntryPoint There was an error during CodePackage activation.The service host terminated with exit code:1"

by moving my setup script to a ps1 file and executing it from the ***MySetup.bat***

So I ended it up with the following in my .bat and .ps1 files.

1. In my ***MySetup.bat*** (the one you reference in the service manifest):

powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ".\MySetup.ps1"

2. In my ***MySetup.ps1*** (add your own PowerShell script here):

netsh http add urlacl url=http://erick1.com:80/ user="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

**How to debug:**

Remote Desktop your Virtual Machine and go to "D:\SvcFab_App[YOUR SERVCE TYPE NAME HERE]\log" and check the .err and .out files. Don't forget to add  to your service manifest.. the entire section would be:

```
<SetupEntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>MySetup.bat</Program>
    <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
    <ConsoleRedirection FileRetentionCount="10"/>
  </ExeHost>
</SetupEntryPoint>
```

One last thing: In my case I had a special char in the .bat file that was not visible in Visual Studio and my setup was failing... I was only able to discovery it by reading the logs ( described above ). Don't be afraid of logs, it's usually one line in this case.

Thanks

Comment: +1 on the comment about "special char in the .bat file".  My issue was probably the same thing.  The UTF-8 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) characters were causing issues when my SetupEntryPoint EXE was trying to execute.  I found it by copying my bat/ps1 files directly to one of the VM's and tried to execute it there.  Found the error real quick that way!

Comment: @PatrickSteele Thanks! This BOM was the source of all my pain, and this comment is the only thing I found anywhere that mentions it at all.

Comment: How did you solve this & get rid of the special char?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because it runs as SYSTEM, which doesn't have a user profile to create the drive mapping in.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get an Azure Files share mounted so that my Guest Executable can use it?

Comment: In Worker Roles we had 'startup tasks' but there doesn't seem to be a straight forward place for this in Service Fabric.

Comment: I think I may have found the answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-runas-security may need to set the RunAsPolicy to allow the SetupEntryPoint executable mount the drive.

Comment: Not sure if your service can see that mapping unless you run it as the same user.